# Can you explain me this 'sed' command and help me improve it?

Tags: sed

I found a command lines and I can't understand what exactly happens.

```
pdftk $1 dump_data | sed -e 's/\(InfoValue:\)\s.*/\1\ /g'
```

In this line the command `sed` is my principal doubt. What exactly is going on?

I'm newbie and I think that in this part `*/\1\` the `sed` command is calling to `$1`, so if I change the `$1` I need change `sed` command. Maybe this form:

```
pdftk out dump_data | sed -e 's/\(InfoValue:\)\s.*/\out\ /g'
```

But as I don't understand the theory of `sed` I can't be sure of my assumption.

Comment: This page (https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) explains Sed from start to
finish, so if you want to learn sed well it is a fantastic resource. Also it
has a great set of other unix tutorials
(https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/index.html). Cheers!

Comment: Do you have an _issue_ with the initial pipeline? Does it not work as intended, or are you trying to modify it in some way to do something that it was not doing from the start?  It is somewhat unusual that you want to know what a random command that you "found" is doing, and you also mention you wanted to "improve" on it (without specifying closer what you meant by that), which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `sed` command is not directly related to the previous command before pipe. The `sed` command only receives the data on standard input. It's not the matter of `sed` theory but the basic principles of shell scripting.

1. `pdftk $1 dump_data` calls the `pdftk` binary (a popular program for PDF maniplations) with two arguments. The first argument is whatever you put as the first argument to the shell script. The second argument to `pdftk` is command `dump_data`.
2. The output of the first command is directly connected via pipe - the `|` symbol - to the second command, which is a `sed` replacement.
3. Any occurrence of the string `InfoValue:` followed by a white space character `\s` and any number of other characters - dot meaning any character and an asterisk meaning any number of repetitions, matches. But in the replacement there is only the first part (in the pair of backslahsed brackets), followed by something white. It is actually not clear, what should be after the last backslash. Final `g` means "replace all occurrences".

Answer (score 2):

```
... | sed -e 's/\(InfoValue:\)\s.*/\1\ /g'
```

The `s/pattern/replacement/g` command looks for all matches of *pattern* on the line, and replaces them with *replacement*. The left-hand part is `\(InfoValue:\)\s.*`, which matches the literal string `InfoValue:` (capturing it because of the parenthesis), then a whitespace (`\s`, a GNUism that probably comes from Perl), then anything (`.*`) up to the end of line. The `\1` in the replacement references the first captured group (the only one here), and the space is a literal space. Since the capture group matches a literal string, it doesn't really need to be captured, the same string could be repeated on the right-hand side. But of course doing it like this gets rid of useless repetition.

So, on any line that contains `InfoValue:` , it removes anything after it.

That's for the input that `sed` reads from the pipe, because that's what `sed` and pipes do: `sed` reads from standard input (when no filename is given), and the pipe connects the standard output of the left-hand command to the standard input of the right-hand command.

That `$1` on the right side is totally unrelated to the `sed`. It's the shell parameter referring to the first command line argument to the script. (Or the shell function if it's used inside it). If it's part of a script, it'd be meant to run as `whatever.sh somefile.pdf`, and it would call [`pdftk`'s `dump_data` operation](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-dump-data)
on the given file.